# Drupal clean url links not working, only home page works while all other link redirect to wamp homepage

Tags: html, drupal, wampserver

I am trying to migrate an existing drupal project to wampserver. The problems is that after setup, only the home page works. All other links redirect to the wampserver home page. However when I use, for example-

> http://localhost/?q=cars/rentbasis

instead of the clean url

> http://localhost/cars/rentbasis

the links work fine. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file if you have one.

When I want to have a clean URL, I put the path to the folder of the web site in my .htaccess.

Here is an example :

```
ErrorDocument 403 /php/TEST/DAS/iRat-tools/rewrite.php?page=error&error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /php/TEST/DAS/iRat-tools/rewrite.php?page=error&error=404
ErrorDocument 500 /php/TEST/DAS/iRat-tools/rewrite.php?page=error&error=500
ErrorDocument 503 /php/TEST/DAS/iRat-tools/rewrite.php?page=error&error=503

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php/TEST/DAS/iRat-tools/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ rewrite.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ rewrite.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ rewrite.php?page=$1&module=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ rewrite.php?page=$1&module=$2 [L]
```

Put your path after the **RewriteBase**

To retrieve your path, it's simple. When you open your site on a browser, you will be on http://localhost/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/MyWebSiteFiles.

The path is: /Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/